# Linear regression analysis examples

Tags: r, regression, self-study, multiple-regression

I am looking for examples where linear regression analysis is used in answering real problems. That is, from formulating real questions as a statistical question, validating assumptions so on to making conclusions.

I think I have a reasonable understanding of various statistical methods. I want to be able to put them in a ordered fashion.

EDIT: I guess I am looking for examples like [this one (pdf)](http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/nelson/courses/st512/Multiple%20Regression%20Example.pdf). In this they look for the relative importance of variables and see whether they can drop any variables or need additional variables. Some examples that include concepts of mediation, controlling for variables, so on would be great. Even if they are in books or research articles.

Comment: There are various of resources on web demonstrate how to use `lm` in R, just do a google search, you will find many. I think you can find many real problems as you mentioned.

Comment: I can use `lm` in R. I also can test hypothesis etc. I want examples where they have put everything together.
I did try to find such examples on the web without much success.

Comment: I think you should state the question more specifically. I think you are not asking the condition when linear regression is working, but asking when should we use it. If you are talking about that, I think the answer is coming from outside statistics, which is the problem itself. Normally, linear regression will come to mind if you think the relationship between variables are linear dependent, but the data is polluted by normal distribute noise.

Comment: My apologies. I have now edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, I do have a suitable list in hand. I suggest you can look for books on R, they usually have examples on `lm`, although mostly not as complex as your example. I think *R in action* and *R by examples* are books with lots of examples.

Comment: Shameless plug for my own work: http://wakimanalytics.com/data-analytics-research/virginia-basketball-has-a-tougher-time-against-good-3pt-shooting-teams-consequence-of-the-pack-line-defense/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [contributed documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) page on CRAN, you can find Faraway's *Practical Regression and Anova using R* ([pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf)).  Chapter 12 (pp. 138-150) is titled "Chicago Insurance Redlining - a complete example".  It walks you though a multiple regression analysis in R from loading the data through evaluating the final model.